# HDD is not readable - can I fix this

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I have two HDD in my system, but today morning the additional hard disk is not readable.
My all data are kept inside the additional HDD.

When I disconnect the additional HDD from my system then system boot as usual, but when I connect HDD my system hangs Up in windows boot logo. Please note this problem is not related to HDD order.

1. When I connect only the additional HDD then system shows this error:

> disk not readable press ctrl+alt+del to restart

2. I can see the name of additional HDD in BIOS.
3. When I connect both HDD i get a continues beep... beeep .. beep
   sound.

Please tell me is my HDD gone dead ? How do I get the data back ? is there any kit for recovering HDD data ?

Comment: Sounds like the drive is dead.  I hope you have backups.

Comment: Is there a way to recover data ? or I lost it forever ?

Comment: Recovering data only works if your system can actually attempt to read it.  If your not even able to boot the system with the hdd connected its simply dead.

Comment: I mean any professional way.. can professional recover the data ?

Comment: Consider getting a USB enclosure and testing it external to the machine.  Professional recovery is certainly an option, but is expensive.  If this data doesn't exist anywhere else, then perhaps the cost is worth while.  Google "data recovery".

Comment: http://www.drivesaversdatarecovery.com/

Comment: @user1983017 - You have a few hundred to a few thousand dollars to spend?  Seagate offers data recovery on their drives, they have decent rates, you pay a flat fee and depending on if they have success additional charges are added.  Only valid on their hdds more then likely.

Comment: @user1983017 Just an FYI, professional data recovery services usually cost anywhere in the hundreds to possibly thousands of dollars (USD) to recover drives. The only free solution to data recovery is A) luck or B) preventative backups.

Comment: FYI, sometimes you can recover the drive for a limited time by freezing it.  You must bag it tightly to avoid moisture getting into the drive.  The small changes made by contraction in freezing will sometimes enable near-dead drives to work for a short while.  However, the more you try to run a dead drive, the less likely that this will work.  It's worked for me perhaps half the time I try it, but sometimes I can only get some of the data off the drive. Sample procedure at http://lifehacker.com/5515337/save-a-failed-hard-drive-in-your-freezer-redux

Comment: can you boot off a live cd while the second drive is connected up? if so, check its SMART stats to get an idea of what may have gone wrong.

Comment: Thanks guys, but from this time I will save my all data to cloud.. I lost very important files.. including my project raw data. I have sent my HDD for recovery.